# How to filter only specific dates from a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 1000 records. I am trying to filter only the below Dates record from the `df`

2020-06-09

2020-08-06

2020-08-25

I have tried the below code hoping that my code will filter only those records available for that particular date.

`df[(df['Date'] == '2020-06-09') & (df['Date'] = '2020-08-06') & (df['Date'] = '2020-08-25')]`

But i am not getting any output. I need to view the dataframe only for those particular dates.

Comment: You need to replace the `&` with `|` operator

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df = df[df['date'].isin(['2020-06-09', '2020-08-06', '2020-08-25'])]
```

---

**Method 2**

```
dates = ['2020-06-09', '2020-08-06', '2020-08-25']
df = df.query("date in @dates")
```